# C++ opencv determining required libs to compile

Tags: c++, opencv, g++

I'm getting started with opencv in C++.When I try to compile my code, I sometimes get strange linker errors such as:undefined reference to symbol '_ZN2cv6circleERKNS_17_InputOutputArrayENS_6Point_IiEEiRKNS_7Scalar_IdEEiii'.

In the past, I've resolved this by googling around and making sure I'm compiling all the necessary opencv libraries. It's a good amount of guesswork on my part, but it solves the error.

Is there a better to do this? That is, determine which opencv libraries need to be compiled. I am using the g++ compiler btw.

Comment: Typically when you decide to use a library, you are supposed read its documentation to see what linker flags you need.

Answer (score 1):

Aplogies. I have found the answer: simple append `pkg-config --cflags --libs opencv` to your compilation cmd